# Can I use a GridViewRowPresenter to merge cells?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridviewrow

I have a ListView and GridView within it. Upon clicking a button on any row I set an error state based on which I need to change that particular row's cell structure. For eg. I need it to go from a 5 column cell to a 3 column one. Can I accomplish this using a GridViewRowPresenter?

Comment: Do you have any sample code? Can you be a little clearer in the explanation of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using a Style trigger in conjunction with a GridViewRowPresenter. I can share the solution (and the problem) if anyone is interested.

Comment: Very interested! Could you post this please?